# ¿Equivalente a InputBox de VB.net en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

> Dado la cantidad de veces que me tope con esta pregunta y no encontre una respuesta clara o directa la voy a formalizar aquí.

Cual es el equivalente al InputBox de `vb.net` o `VBA` en `C#`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conseguir acceder al `Inputbox` se debe hacer un puente con las referencias de los controles de `VisualBasic` para esto se deben seguir los siguientes pasos.

> Paso 1

En el explorador de soluciones buscamos el apartado `Referencias`, hacemos click secundario y clickeamos en `Agregar referencia...`

[image: Paso 1]

> Paso 2

Una vez dentro filtramos por `visual`, `microsoft.visualbasic`, `VisualBasic`, etc... y tildamos en la referencia llamada `Microsoft.VisualBasic`

[image]

> Paso 3

declaramos la referencia ingresando `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;` al inicio de nuestro codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Paso 4

Llamamos dentro de la función al control `Interaction.InputBox();` y asignamos los parámetros que pide, en la imagen de abajo pongo un ejemplo de los parámetros que indica aunque el `intellisense` de Visual studio ayuda bastante

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No estoy seguro de que esta sea la mejor solución.. incluir toda la librería de VisualBasic para usar un método?, posiblemente una mejor alternativa sea crear una clase imitando ese comportamiento..

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal la libreria ya esta incluida en .net... no se agranda el exe ni nada.. como solucion rapida es viable

Answer (score 1):

No hay un equivalente

[InputBox [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/inputbox/)

pero si esta la posibilidad de crear el form dinamicamente usando codigo y encapsular todo en una clase

creas un class y dentro pones este codigo

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

public static DialogResult InputBox(string title, string promptText, ref string value)
{
  Form form = new Form();
  Label label = new Label();
  TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
  Button buttonOk = new Button();
  Button buttonCancel = new Button();

  form.Text = title;
  label.Text = promptText;
  textBox.Text = value;

  buttonOk.Text = "OK";
  buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
  buttonOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
  buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

  label.SetBounds(9, 20, 372, 13);
  textBox.SetBounds(12, 36, 372, 20);
  buttonOk.SetBounds(228, 72, 75, 23);
  buttonCancel.SetBounds(309, 72, 75, 23);

  label.AutoSize = true;
  textBox.Anchor = textBox.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
  buttonOk.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
  buttonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

  form.ClientSize = new Size(396, 107);
  form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { label, textBox, buttonOk, buttonCancel });
  form.ClientSize = new Size(Math.Max(300, label.Right + 10), form.ClientSize.Height);
  form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
  form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
  form.MinimizeBox = false;
  form.MaximizeBox = false;
  form.AcceptButton = buttonOk;
  form.CancelButton = buttonCancel;

  DialogResult dialogResult = form.ShowDialog();
  value = textBox.Text;
  return dialogResult;
}
```

asi solo haces

```
string value;
var dialogResult = NombreClass.InputBox("Titulo", "Descripcion:", ref value);

if(dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
   TextBox1.Text = value;
}
```

Comment: Un honor tu presencia Leandro. Pero si existe un equivalente tal como comento en mi respuesta.

Comment: Pero eso no es un equivalente, basicamente importas una libreria que fue creada en un lenguaje diferente a c#, ademas de estar importando mucha otra funcionalidad que quizas no sea necesaria, hay que evaluar si se quiere importar componentes de vb.net por solo un dialogo

Comment: Leandro, estas desviando el post a un sitio muy abierto sobre que cosas son necesarias y cuales no. Tanto tu respuesta como la que yo hice son igual de correctas. La persona que entre en la posteridad elegirá con cual quedarse, la tuya es mas enfocada y la mía es para "salir del apuro". Saludos